# R and Shiny: object not found

Tags: r, shiny

**EDITED to include full UI and sample data**

I did read the other StackOverflow qs on this issue, but none seemed to address the cause of my error.

When the app loads, I get "error object [name of district I've selected] not found" for the District (inputID = "d"). I know it must be an issue with the subsetting reactive in the server, but I've tried everything (loading the data in the server, removing the vector from the filter function, changing the data type of the variables).

I also took this code from another Shiny App I built, which works. I can't see any differences between the two, besides that one is geom_point() and this is geom_col() so again, not sure what is going on.

Thanks!

Sample data:

```
sample <- sample_n(pop, 10)

dput(sample)

structure(list(GazID = c(NA, NA, "13872", NA, "13610", "13985", 
"13984", "13434", "13428", "13631"), Province = c("Niolandskaia", 
"Kaluzhskaia", "Iaroslavskaia", "Vyborgskaia", "Moskovskaia", 
"Volynskaia", "Volynskaia", "Orenburgskaia", "Orenburgskaia", 
"Arkhangel'skaia"), District = c(NA, "Suhinichinbezuezdniigorod", 
"Romanov", NA, "Zvenigorod", "Kovel", "Lutsk", "Ufa", "Orenburg", 
"Mezen"), TotalPop = c(NA, NA, 104104, NA, 71746, 103381, 102779, 
93145, 62740, 26796), Male = c(NA, NA, 48604, NA, 36948, 52266, 
50393, 46403, 32617, 13078), Female = c(NA, NA, 55500, NA, 34798, 
51115, 52386, 46742, 30123, 13718), City = c(NA, 5552, NA, NA, 
1253, 4254, 5552, 6682, 9533, NA), Rural = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
70493, 99127, 97228, 86483, 53207, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Above the UI:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(rebus)

pop <- read_csv("pop.csv") 

pop$TotalPop <- str_replace_all(pop$TotalPop, pattern = fixed(","), replacement = "") 
pop$Male <- str_replace_all(pop$Male, pattern = fixed(","), replacement = "") 
pop$Female <- str_replace_all(pop$Female, pattern = fixed(","), replacement = "") 
pop$City <- str_replace_all(pop$City, pattern = fixed(","), replacement = "") 
pop$Rural <- str_replace_all(pop$Rural, pattern = fixed(","), replacement = "") 
pop$District <- str_remove_all(pop$District, pattern = "[^[:alnum:]]") 
pop$TotalPop <- as.numeric(pop$TotalPop)
pop$Male <- as.numeric(pop$Male)
pop$Female <- as.numeric(pop$Female)
pop$City <- as.numeric(pop$City)
pop$Rural <- as.numeric(pop$Rural)
pop$GazID <- as.character(pop$GazID)
pop$District <- str_trim(pop$District)
```

The UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Population Data from VSO"),

   sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = "y", #internal label 
                    label = "Population to map", #label that user sees
                    choices = c("Total population" = "TotalPop", 
                                "Male population" = "Male", 
                                "Female population" = "Female",
                                "Urban population" = "City",
                                "Rural population" = "Rural"),
                    selected = "TotalPop"),

        selectizeInput(inputId = "d", 
                       label = "Select district", 
                       choices = c(pop$District), 
                       multiple = TRUE, # can choose multiple 
                       options = list(maxItems = 5))), 


      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("plot")
      )
   )
)
```

The server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
      pop_subset <- reactive({
        req(input$d)
        filter(pop, District %in% c(input$d)
               )})

 output$plot <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(data = pop_subset(), aes_string(x = pop_subset()$District, y =     input$y)) + 
          geom_col(aes(fill = pop_subset()$District)) + 
          labs(x = "District", y = "Population") +
          scale_fill_discrete(name = "Districts")
})}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to include `pop_subset()$` in your `aes(...)` since you already include it as `data=pop_subset()`, suggest `aes(x=District,y=input$y)`, same for `fill=`. In the previous block, where you do you define `pop`? This question is good but still not reproducible, as the `ui` component is incomplete (do you do anything fancy) and we do not have your data or something reminiscent. Can you fill out just enough of the missing components to make it easier to troubleshoot?

Comment: When I remove the pop_subset()$ from the aes(...) calls, I get a new error "District not found"

Comment: Yes, I didn't expect it would fix the problem, but it is still unnecessary in this example. Can you update the example?

Comment: I updated the example. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for filling out `ui`, that's helpful. Beside what I'm inferring is `dplyr`, are there any other non-base packages you are using? Also, we still don't know what `"pop.csv"` looks like, can you include the output of `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative sampling of the whole data? If it is more than 10 rows or so, please don't post the whole thing.

Comment: Yes - tidyverse includes dplyr, ggplot etc. Also using readr for the csv and stringr for data cleaning. I'll post a sample of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `aes_string` in your `ggplot`, but trying to pass `District` without quotes. I realize you need `aes_string` because you are using `input$y`, so just change your plot call to

```
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(pop_subset())
    ggplot(data = pop_subset(), aes_string(x = "District", y =     input$y)) + 
      geom_col(aes(fill = District)) + 
      labs(x = "District", y = "Population") +
      scale_fill_discrete(name = "Districts")
  })
```

---

For reproducibility, packages and some sample data (no idea of its true representative nature, doesn't really matter I think).

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)
n <- 50
pop <- data_frame(
  TotalPop = sample(1e4, size=n, replace=TRUE)
) %>%
  mutate(
    Male = pmax(0, TotalPop - sample(1e4, size=n, replace=TRUE)),
    Female = TotalPop - Male,
    City = sample(LETTERS, size=n, replace=TRUE),
    District = sample(letters, size=n, replace=TRUE)
  )
```

Comment: WOW THIS WORKS! I am so happy. Thank you. Really really helpful.

Comment: FYI, loops, it's okay to generate fake data in questions, as I did above. It can often be much easier to do it that way (don't forget `set.seed` if using randomness) than including real data, and in many times will protect sensitive/proprietary data.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you.